# Hooking sys_send

Tags: c, linux, kernel-module

I am writing a kernel module in which I am hooking the syscall table and redirect a number of syscalls. I have done this with two methods. The traditional method where you find the address of the syscall table and make the memory rw as described [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=139406), and for cases such as exec and fork I search for the relevant function symbol (`do_fork`, `do_execve`) and replace its reference with one for my own function such as done [here](http://cormander.com/2012/05/hijacking-linux-kernel-pointers/).

I currently am trying to hook `sys_send`, but have been encountering several problems. When I try to do it the traditional way:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <asm/paravirt.h>

ref_sys_send = (void *)sys_call_table[__NR_send];
sys_call_table[__NR_send] = (unsigned long *)new_sys_send;
```

I get the error:

```
error: ‘__NR_send’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I searched in lxr and found that `__NR_send` is defined in around 16 different header files with various different values.

I also tried to hook it using the second method, but was not able to find the relevant function that is to `sys_send` as `do_fork` is to `sys_fork`.

Could someone tell me 1) where to find the correct value for `__NR_send` so that I can hook it from the syscall table, 2) what is the name of the function that contains the actual c code executed for `sys_send` like `do_fork` does for `sys_fork` and what file it is located in, or even better both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more hours of searching, I finally found that sys_send is defined in `Linux/net/socket.c` through the macro

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE4(send, int, fd, void __user *, buff, size_t, len,
                 unsigned int, flags)
{
         return sys_sendto(fd, buff, len, flags, NULL, 0);
}
```

It is then possible to simply hook sys_sendto using `__NR_sendto` and check for the NULL argument to know if the call was originally send or sendto.